# How to copy-paste cell contents of new lines into a cell?

Tags: debian, spreadsheet, wps-office

Assume you have the following content in clipboard

```
Yt rauhallinen.

Lorem ipsun loremp.
```

If you paste it into a cell in any spreadsheet editor, you get the content in many cells.

Expected output: the content in one cell after paste.

OS: Linux Debian Stretch 9.1
Spreadsheet editor: WPS Spreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

You can double click on the cell or press F2 to enter the edit mode and then paste the text there. That works for me in LibreOffice.

Comment: F2 does not work in WPS Spreadsheet. - - Double clicking the cell or the formula bar works. - - What is the F2 feature called?

Comment: I'm not sure why the F2 shortcut key has not worked for you. Here is the quote from the WPS Spreadsheet documentation. `F2 - Edits the active cell and positions the insertion point at the end of the cell contents.` ... take a look at the full shortcut documentation here https://help.wps.com/articles/list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-for-spreadsheets ... the behavior is the same as in LibreOffice.